# using spring batch for writing from file to db with one to many

Tags: spring-batch

From excel file I construct a  Report object this contain multiple Audit objects  and  each Audit contains multiple Finding objects , (audit without findings is incomplete so audit and its findings must be saved in one transaction each finding will have FK to audit   and each audit will have FK to report). I want to use spring batch to persists  this  using spring-jdbc.
from my understanding I can go with two steps

First Step

1. read from  a file into Report Object,
2. no processor
3. then  write Report to database,  put audits from   report  object into
       job ExecutionContext

Second step

1. Read audits from job ExecutionContext,
2. no processor
3. writer will use CompositeItemWriter to save  audit with its 
   findings

Please advice   is this  write approach or is there any better  way for   dealing with parent and multiple children

Comment: I think you can use a single step with a custom ItemReadem, but this depends on how your input file's structure (records sequence, I meant); there are some examples in SO and around the net about this kind of problems. Search and try some approch and when you have some specific problem came back and ask for help.

Comment: how to accomplish  this in one step?
 if reader returns each audit from report instead of report,how  can I pass the report to writer?  audit table has  fk  to report.id so audit needs  report present before audit.